# Excel Nested If - Calculating Commission

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I need to calculate the sales commission depending on the sales achievement.

```
AMOUNT       PERCENT             NOTE
8000-9999        5%            achievement*.05
10000-11999     20%            difference of achievement-8000*.2+400
12000-13999     25%            difference of achievement-8000*.25+400
14000-15999     30%            difference of achievement-8000*.30+400
16000 & ABOVE   35%            difference of achievement-8000*.35+400
```

I have this in excel formula,

```
=IF(H3>8000,(H3*0.05),IF(H3<9999,H3*0.05,IF(H3>10000,((H3-8000)*0.2+400),IF(H3<11999,((H3-8000)*0.2+400),IF(H3>12000,((H3-8000)*0.25+400),IF(H3<13999,((H3-8000)*0.25+400),IF(H3>14000,((H3-8000)*0.3+400),IF(H3<15999,((H3-8000)*0.3+400),IF(H3>16000,((H3-8000)*0.35+400))))))))))
```

I tested with

```
Achieved Amount         Commission
8724                    436.2        //correct
10000                   500          //wrong
```

I believed the other formula was not read.

Comment: You mixed your `value_if_false` with an `AND` operator. Your code would be much easier to read (and to debug) if you just use `AND(condition1, condition2)` within each `IF` condition

Comment: You are on the right lines, all you need to do is to do the highest first then the next highest etc. At the moment as soon as it is 8001 then that is true and the calculation stops. So, if you test for 16001 and it is not true then it will do the next one etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your pattern this will do what you want:

```
=IF(H3<10000,H3*0.05,(H3-8000)*MIN((INT(H3/2000)-1),7)*0.05+400)
```

[image]

Comment: This can be shortened still because `H3*0.05` is the same thing as `(H3-8000)*0.05+400`, which is the same form as the other ones.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 but to go with my formula the percentage would need to be `15%` not `5%`  It does not fit the pattern.  The result is the same at `5%` but I would still need the IF to change from `15%` to `5%` on my formula.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @ScottCraner Touche!

Answer (score 0):

So, as my comment you need to reverse it:

```
=if(H3>16000,H3*0.35,if(H3>14000,H3*0.3,if(H3>12000,H3*0.25,if(h3>10000,H3*0.2,if(H3>8000,H3*0.05,0)))))
```

Not tested this, or put in the constant amounts you show either but the structure should work.

You are on the right lines, all you need to do is to do the highest first then the next highest etc. At the moment as soon as it is 8001 then that is true and the calculation stops. So, if you test for 16001 and it is not true then it will do the next one etc

Comment: Technically correct, but huge nested `IF` statements make me shudder a bit. Other solutions (such as ScottCraner's) are shorter and easier to read.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 yes huge if statements are a challenge to keep the logic together, excel used to have a 7 layer limit back in the day - but aparently they removed that. So, about the only thing going for my answer is that it shows it can be done - there is always another way in excel...